# Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> giving NullReferenceException when .AddRange is called

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am trying to add both `config.ContainerNames` and `container` to my `public Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> ListContainerData {get; internal set;}`. However I am running into a`NullReferenceException`.

**ListContainer()**

```
public static Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> ListContainer(StartConfig config)

    {

        if (config != null || config.BlobClient != null)
        {
            config = Program.GetConfig();
        }
        if (config == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
        }
        if (config.BlobClient == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("BlobClient must not be null", "config");
        }
        List<string> container = new List<string>();

        //Get the list of the blob from the above container
        IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = config.BlobClient.ListContainers();


        foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
        {
            container.Add(item.Name);

            config.ContainerNames.Add(String.Join("\n", container));

        }

        config.ListContainerData.Item2.AddRange(config.ContainerNames);
        config.ListContainerData.Item1.AddRange(container);

        //Adding a print statement

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", container));
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        // Console.WriteLine(startConfig.ContainerNames.ToString());

        return config.ListContainerData;


    }
```

**StartConfig klass**

```
public class StartConfig
{
    public StartConfig()
    {
        ContainerNames = new List<string>();
    }

    public CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount { get; internal set; }
    public CloudBlobClient BlobClient { get; internal set; }
    public CloudBlobContainer Container { get; internal set; }

    public List<string> ContainerNames { get; internal set; }

    public Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> ListContainerData { get; internal set; }

}
```

I am not sure why `config.ListContainerData.Item1.AddRange(container);` && `config.ListContainerData.Item2.AddRange(config.ContainerNames);` are both throwing the Null exception, Could someone explain why this is happening and how I to resolve the Null exception? Thank you!

Comment: i dont see `config.ListContainerData` instantiated anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `ListContanierData` and  those two lists before adding them:

```
public static Tuple<List<string>,List<string>> ListContainer(StartConfig config)

{

    if (config != null || config.BlobClient != null)
    {
        config = Program.GetConfig();
    }
    if (config == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
    }
    if (config.BlobClient == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("BlobClient must not be null", "config");
    }
    List<string> container = new List<string>();

    //Get the list of the blob from the above container
    IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = config.BlobClient.ListContainers();


    foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
    {
        container.Add(item.Name);

        config.ContainerNames.Add(String.Join("\n", container));

    }

    config.ListContainerData = new Tuple<List<string>, List<string>>(new List<string>(), new List<string>());
    //or
    //config.ListContainerData = Tuple.Create(new List<string>(), new List<string>());
    config.ListContainerData.Item2.AddRange(config.ContainerNames);
    config.ListContainerData.Item1.AddRange(container);

    //Adding a print statement

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", container));
    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    // Console.WriteLine(startConfig.ContainerNames.ToString());

    return config.ListContainerData;


}
```

Comment: Instead of using the ctor for `Tuple`, you can just use `Tuple.Create(new List<string>(), new List<string>());`.

Comment: Thank you Nikola! I see where my mistake was now !

Comment: you're welcome jdave ! :)
@juharr That's true, i'll expand my answer accordingly, thanks!